# Use Catch with a timer to return to the function

Tags: java, github, egit, github-api

I am using the **GitHub API**, but it throws an exception because of the rate limit.
I use `catch` to catch this exception, but I want to use a timer count 1 hour and continue the function from where it stopped.

```
try{
      // my function
}
catch (NoSuchPageException e ) {
    Thread.sleep(3600 * 1000);
    System.out.println("Waiting the timer");            
}
```

How can I continue my function after the timer ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can use a while loop.

```
boolean continueFunc = false;
while (!continueFunc)
    try{
        //my function
        continueFunc = true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchPageException e ){
        Thread.sleep(3600 * 1000);
        System.out.println("Waiting the timer");            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but if you wish to retrieve html content but continue if you content is not there 1 hour later after calling the function you can use futures:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class FutureExample {

    static class RetrieveHTMLThingy implements Callable<String> {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Getting HTML Stuff");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            return "html stuff";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        FutureTask<String> getHTML = new FutureTask<String>(new RetrieveHTMLThingy());
        executor.execute(getHTML);
        try {
            System.out.println(getHTML.get(1, TimeUnit.HOURS));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```